# MSAL.js - Implicit Authentication - Issue with reply url parameters

Tags: azure-active-directory, msal.js

I am using MSAL.js for a javascript based single page application.
We have configure Azure Ad for implicit authentication.
The redirection url also has been configured to a page.

However we have a requirement where we get a daily email report. This email has links to the application page but with query parameters that allows to filter the report for that day.

Now if we access the app via the landing page, we are able to login fine. But with the query params it gives the exception "The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs..".

I am using the endpoint V2 on Azure AD , hence not able to put * in the reply url. I guess this is an existing problem. But is there some way to overcome the issue of logging in & redirection with parameters?

Thanks,
Ash

Answer (score 0):

The approach we have taken in general with our apps is to specify a specific URL to MSAL as the redirect URL, and redirect to the "local URL" from there.
So when you send a user to authenticate, you store the current path somewhere like in local/session storage.
Then when the user hits that callback page, you can load up the path from storage and redirect the user there.
This way you can avoid wildcard usage, and still get the user where they wanted to go.

You can tell MSAL not to redirect to the current URL and specify the redirect URL like this:

```
const app = new UserAgentApplication({
  auth: {
    // Other settings left out for brevity
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
    redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/auth-callback'
  }
});
```

Comment: ok thanks for the details. We did think about an intermediate page to handle it by caching the params. But wanted to know if there was a more cleaner solution available by the library. Will try out what you suggested.
Cheers!!

Comment: This approach is essentially what is recommended in the documentation too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url?s=09#use-a-state-parameter. Though that uses the state parameter instead of local/session storage. The documentation also has a good point about open redirection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

In Case of SPA with login redirect at landing on page with querystring parameter you can use the following configuration to preserve querystring parameter after login (MSAL 2.0)

```
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
      clientId: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
      authority: "YOUR_AUTHORITY_URL",
      redirectUri: window.location.origin
    }
```